# Scrum Board: Confusion with Product Backlog Item Column

Tags: scrum, scrumboard

I am doing an assignment on Scrum. But I am not sure whether my scrum board is correct or not. Here is my scrum table during the first week of sprint:

[image]

Here is my scrum table during the second and final week of sprint:
[image]

At the end of the second week, all of my tasks are finished. That's why, there's no item in "To Do" and "In Progress" column.

Now here is the confusing part. Do I have to move all the items from the column entitled **Product Backlog Item**? Or they will stay just like they are now in the table? I mean, am I supposed to move the things of **Product Backlog Items** column to **Done** column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two backlogs in Scrum: the Product Backlog and the Sprint Backlog.

The Product Backlog contains all the work items we know are needed for a product. The Sprint Backlog contains a set of Product Backlog items that have been selected for the sprint.

In your table the "To Do" column represents your Sprint Backlog.

During Sprint Planning you guess at your *sprint capacity*, this is how much work you think you can get done in a sprint. Then you take items from the Product Backlog and add them to the Sprint Backlog until you have reached that capacity.

If you happen to get all of the Sprint Backlog items done before the end of the sprint then you have a choice of what to do:

- You can spend some time preparing for the next sprint
- You can do some tidying up: for example complete some technical debt, update some documentation, etc.
- You can take *one or more* items from the Product Backlog and add it to the sprint

The third option requires that you have work items on the Product Backlog that are *ready* - i.e. there is nothing stopping you bringing them into the sprint. You should also be confident that you have sufficient time to complete any items you bring into the sprint like this.

Comment: OK. Is the second screenshot that I had posted with the question correct?

Comment: Your second screenshot shows what I would expect at the end of a sprint, when you have completed all the planned work.